# adonis in vegan: Can I use it for four factors?

Tags: r, factors, vegan

I want to compare prey composition across groups and, based on other papers, I found that the adonis function was a good option, however I want to test 4 factors and I am not sure if that is an issue. I also would like to know how to choose the correct order in the formula as it seems to affect the results.
Can someone help me?

This is what I have:

> perm1<-adonis(dist.Y~Location+Species+Sex+Size, data, method= "binomial", permutations=999)

It works fine, I'm just not sure it is correct to do it this way.
Also is it correct to do it with a single factor?

I just want to make sure my results are correct.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with including four factors, but you might want to look at using `adonis2` instead of `adonis`.

With `adonis2` you can use the `by` argument to specify what you want to test. `by` = "terms" will assess significance for each term (sequentially from first to last), setting `by` = "margin" will assess the marginal effects of the terms (each marginal term analysed in a model with all other variables), `by` = "onedf" will analyse one-degree-of-freedom contrasts sequentially, `by` = NULL will assess the overall significance of all terms together.

Therefore, unlike in the original `adonis` function, the order of the variables doesn't matter unless you select `by` = "terms". I suspect you would be interested in marginal testing of variables using the `by`="marginal" parameter, where the output gives a partial R-squared for each variable in the model.